# Vuex getters-properties Failure when using vue-router - they failed to be reactive

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

First, there is  `user.js`, which is one of the modules for `store.js`

```
const state = {
  isLogin: false
}

const mutations = {
  login(state, userid){
    state.userid = userid;
  }
}

export default {
  state,
  mutations
}
```

Using Vue-router, I created an App Component, and imported `store.js`.
And then comes the Component `login.vue`. Following is part of the codes:

```
<script>    
export default {
  vuex: {
    actions: {
        login  // this action changes the state of
               // isLogin by dispatch `login` mutation
    }
  },

  methods: {
    btnClick(){
      // here calls the login action
    }
  }
} 
</script>
```

I noticed that the method `btnClick` can work in this component. It did changed the `store.state.user.isLogin`.

But here is another component `a.vue` listening the `isLogin` state:

```
<template>
...
  <a
    v-if="isLogin" 
    v-link="'#'">
    ...
  </a>
...
</template>

<script>
// import something
export default {
    vuex: {
      getters: {
        isLogin: ({ user }) => user.isLogin
      }
    }
}
</script>
```

When `btnClick` toggled in `login.vue`, the `isLogin` changed. But it seems that though the getter `isLogin` in `a.vue` was changed, the`v-if`in `<a>` was not able to be reactive, for the `<a>` didn't appear.

I have tried to test if `store` is injected to child Components, and the result is it have passed. Also, I have tried to use `computed` instead of `getters` to listen `isLogin`, and it failed to be reactive either. when adding `isLogin` in `watch` attributes, it failed to watch.

And there is one thing that I am quite sure -- the `Vue.use(Vuex)` is not missed.

I was wondering whether it is the `Vue-router` which caused the problem.
And it seems that no one have asked questions about `vuex` with `vue-router`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using `vuex` with `vue-router` and `vue-resource` (if you are authenticating users I assume that you are making HTTP requests) and it works just fine.

I think that your problem is your getter declaration. Getters receive the `state` inside the `store` object, and in your store declaration I don't see that the `isLogin` option is a property of `user`. I would change your getter to this.

```
vuex: {
  getters: {
    isLogin: state => state.isLogin
  }
}
```

Comment: I think when you do a modular Vuex build, as he has done here, the module itself becomes a property on `state`.  So since it was a module called `user`, it does become a property of state, and the `isLogin` property would be at `state.user.isLogin`

Comment: I see. This is just my foolish mistake. Now it works! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Are you updating `isLogin` anywhere?  You are logging in a user by setting a non-existing property on `state` called `userid`, and not setting `state.isLogin` anywhere. I don't know if setting that non-declared property will work, and also generally in Vue a variable has to be declared from the start in order to be responsive.  Should look like:

```
const state = {
  isLogin: false,
  userid:0
}

const mutations = {
  login(state, userid){
    state.userid = userid;
    state.isLogin = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answering. I have solved this problem so far. As you see, I just made a silly mistake. 

Answer (score 0):

as Jeff says, for my problem, I also make a module, so we have to make it like this

`state.user.isLogin`